# Помогите решить задачу на Python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, алгоритм

**Задача:**

Миша купил себе новый YouPhone. После очередного обновления в системе пропал счетчик процентов зарядов и пользоваться им стало очень сложно. Миша подробно изучал характеристики перед покупкой, поэтому он знает, что:

- с 100% до 0% телефон разряжается ровно за a минут, при этом он теряет заряд равномерно
- с 0% до 100% телефон заряжается ровно за b минут, при этом зарядка так же идет равномерно
- зарядка не может опускаться ниже 0% или становиться выше 100%

В течение дня Миша постоянно перемещался и его телефон менял источник энергии n раз (с зарядки от сети на аккумулятор и наоборот). Известно, что в начале дня (в 00:00) телефон стоял на зарядке и был полностью заряжен. Помогите Мише найти оставшийся в конце дня процент заряда на его телефон.

**Формат входных данных:**

Первая строка входного файла содержит числа n, a, b — количество смен источника энергии телефона, время разряда и заряда аккумулятора соответственно.

Каждая из следующих n строк содержит время суток в формате «hh:mm», в которое была произведена смена источника питания. Данные уникальны и перечислены в хронологическом порядке

**Формат выходных данных:**

В выходной файл выведите процент заряда батареи в 23:59 с точностью четыре знака после запятой.

**Мое решение: (неправильное)**

```
    n, a, b = map(int,input().split()) 
    #комментарий - входные данные 
    x = 100 
    #комментарий - процент заряда 
    g, h = map(int,input().split(':')) 
    #комментарий - ввод времени 
    z = h + (60 * g) 
    #комментарий - переводим часы в минуты и складываем 
    for i in range(n-1): 
    g, h = map(int,input().split(':')) 
    v = h + (60 * g) 
    x = x - a / (z - v) 
    #Комментарий - 
    g, h = map(int,input().split(':')) 
    z = h + (60 * g) 
    x = x - b / (z + v) 
    print(x)
```

Помогите, пожалуйста, решить задачу.

Comment: Вы сами код писали? Знаете, что в Python отступы являются элементами синтаксиса? И не видно, где учитывается `зарядка не может опускаться ниже 0% или становиться выше 100%`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Что же, давай разбираться...

1. В цикле ты два раза вводишь g и h, поэтому вторую строчку `g, h = map(int, input().split(':'))` стоит убрать.
2. Заведи переменную `count`, чтобы знать когда телефон снимают с зарядки и меняй её с `false` на `true` после каждой итерации.
3. Почему ты `a` или `b` делишь на время, должно быть наоборот.
4. Почему из `x` ты вычитаешь дробь? Домножай на 100, чтобы получить проценты, то есть примерно: `x = x - (z - v) / a * 100`.
5. Если честно я вообще не понял, что такое `z` и `v`. Могу предложить сделать `z - количество минут с прошлой записи`, тогда `x = max(x - 100 * (z / a), 0)` или `x = min(x + 100 * (z / b), 100)`, если аккумулятор разряжается или заряжается соответственно.